# RGB strip led controlled by Wemos D1 mini

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, led-strip

I have read some threads in this forum about choosing the correct MOSFET needed to drive RGB LEDs, but I have some doubts.

I started with this scheme:
[image]

But I have some doubts about the Vout of the Wemos, 3.3 V which is not enough to have a low Rds(on) is this right?

I need to drive long LED strips (5 m) and therefore approximately 7 A of current.

Is the easiest way to use a MOSFET driver?

https://kno.wled.ge/basics/compatible-led-strips/

Comment: HI there! You should edit *the source for that picture* into your question. There's a site mentioned in lower left corner, but add the full link not just the site.

Comment: Enrico Camilloni - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help]. (b) As commented above, note the [site rule](/help/referencing) requiring that if a post copies or adapts content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage / PDF etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your question to include the original source webpage for each image (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). TY

Comment: Enrico Camilloni - You posted an "answer", but it wasn't your confirmed solution to your original question, so that was the wrong place to post. Instead your "answer" seemed to be asking for clarification of another answer, so I converted it into a [clarification comment](/help/privileges/comment) there. || FYI If you want to add image links in a comment, you can use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. The draft answer (or question) is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the IRLZ44N, the threshold voltage is 1-2V, so it will turn on with 3.3V. The value of R<sub>DS</sub> on was your concern, we have this as given for V<sub>GS</sub>=4V, R<sub>DS</sub>= 0.035Ω, sinking 21A. Lets just take this as a starting point, assume the values would stay the same at 7A, so you're burning 7*7*0.035 = 1.715 W in the transistor. Seems pretty reasonable to me. 
I'm assuming the values will stay the same, because we aren't given any more information on this in the datasheet, so lets add a factor in for some safety. Even if the R<sub>DS</sub> was significantly worse, say 0.07Ω, you'd still be well within the transistors's operating conditions so I'd really have no concerns with this.

You are right though to assert that a greater V<sub>GS</sub> reduces R<sub>DS</sub>. You could decrease this to 0.022Ω with a V<sub>GS</sub> of 10V. In this particular case, you'd reduce the power dissipated in the transistor from around 1.715W to 1.078W. If you really needed that increased efficiency then you might decide to add a Mosfet driver, though I doubt it.

Comment: so, do you think that can I use the schematics above and the IRLZ44N?
I had doubts about this mosfet after reading this post...
[Logic Level MOSFET IRLZ44N - under Wemos mini](/q/452390) According this graph the voltage drop between drain and source is only 0,25V... and Rds will be 0,036ohm [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edP6g.png)

Comment: making a comparison:
-IRLZ44N Rds=0,025ohm@Vgs=5V and Id=25A
-STB55NF06L Rds=0,02ohm@Vgs=5V and Id=27,5A
so maybe the second is slightly better, right?

Answer (score 1):

The IRLZ44N will work but only with heatsinking.  RDSon is 35mΩ at Vgs = 4.0V; I would not be surprised if RDSon were closer to 50mΩ at Vgs = 3.3V.  But let's assume it's 35mΩ; 7A generates 1.715W in the die, which translates to a junction temperature rise of 106C above ambient, which is within the 175C Tj(max), but will mean that the exposed flange sits at a burn hazard temperature of about 124C.  Meanwhile, Fig. 4 from the datasheet shows that your RDSon will rise by ~1.5x to 53mΩ so now you're trying to dissipate more than 2.5W and your junction temperature will go well past Tj(max) and you're in thermal runaway.

You can find a suitable TO-220 heatsink for a buck or two (don't forget your thermal interface material!) or get a MOSFET with a lower RDSon, or both. You could also use the WEMOS to drive some small NPN BJTs to control +12V to the gate of the IRLZ44N, but that would only drop your heat generation down to ~1W so you'd still have to heatsink.  It would free you from having to use logic level MOSFETs so you might be able to find something with a low enough RDSon at Vgs = 12V to forgo heatsinks entirely.

Comment: So the "only" problem could be the mosfet cooling, instead the operative range is ok...

Comment: Correct, if you put a heatsink on it, it should work.